# Dictionary {cell1:cell2} from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Let's assume that we wave following DF:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Indicator |    Value    |
+-----------+-------------+
| gnipc     |      540.00 |
| survinf   |  1157321.00 |
| Pop       | 38928341.00 |
| u5mort    |       62.28 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

and I would like to create a dictionary:

```
{'gnipc':540.00,
 'survinf':1157321.00,
 'Pop':38928341.00,
 'u5mort':62.28}
```

When I'm doing

```
dict = df.to_dict('records')
```

I'm getting list of dictionaries:

```
[{'Indicator': 'gnipc', 'Value': 540.0},
 {'Indicator': 'survinf', 'Value': 1157321.0},
 {'Indicator': 'Pop', 'Value': 38928341.0},
 {'Indicator': 'u5mort', 'Value': 62.28}]
```

and I have to make additional steps to get desired dictionary.
How can I get this:

```
{'gnipc':540.00,
 'survinf':1157321.00,
 'Pop':38928341.00,
 'u5mort':62.28}
```

in most efficient way?

Comment: `df.set_index('Indicator')['Value'].to_dict()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it.

```
result = {row["Indicator"]: row["Value"] for row in df.to_dict('records')}
```